# Back-calculating primal solutions from solutions to the dual (linear programming, Stata)

Tags: stata, linear-programming

I am doing a simple linear programming data-envelopment analysis in Stata using the "dea" command. I'm analyzing banking institutions in Nepal.

The command returns the efficiencies of the banks themselves (which is great), and the input / output slacks. I don't really want the slacks as much as I want the coefficients in the primal problem. This package will not give them to me. Is there a way to take the efficiencies and the slacks and back-calculate the solution to the primal?

Here are some example results, where `theta` is the objective function to be minimzed

```
DMU     theta
A   0.433222
B   0.364481
C   1
D   0.75502
```

And the slacks:

```
DMU inSlack1    inSlack2    inSlack3    inSlack4    outSlack
A   0           0           0.419444    0           1.17732 
B   0           0           5.91197     5.24498     0
C   0           0           0           0           0
D   0           3.14159     0.87541     0           0
```

Comment: Does it give you the duals? The duals of the dual model are equal to the primal levels.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin. All it gives me are solutions to the dual. Just the coefficients / unknowns in the objective function.